# How to report a bug in the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been searching and searching, but I can't find out how to report a bug in the LinkedIn API.

[LinkedIn's Developer site](https://developer.linkedin.com) is completely devoid of any mention of bugs.  Even Googling "How to report a bug in the LinkedIn API" yields nothing.

[LinkedIn's Developer Support page](https://developer.linkedin.com/support) says that "[engineers] collaborate on questions tagged "linkedin" at Stack Overflow."  There are two problems with using SO for reporting this bug:

1. StackOverflow is not a bug reporting platform.
2. The bug report requires authentication to demonstrate.  We cannot publicly disclose this information.

How do I report a non-security-related LinkedIn API bug?

Comment: ...waiting patiently for all of those engineers from LinkedIn that collaborate on questions here! :)

Comment: *ostensibly collaborate :P

Comment: Did you ever figure that out?

Comment: @pinkpanther - Nope; but the day that a LinkedIn engineer checks SO, he/she will see this question as one of the top #linkedin questions and hopefully... do... something?

Comment: Onlyif that engineer is in a position of high credibility at LinkedIn May be this question/link should be posted in LinkedIn. So some one might stumble across this.

Comment: Try the "contact us" page. Maybe they can tell you what to do with a bug report:
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask

Comment: I found another bug and tried to report it to LinkedIn via the "Contact Us" method.  The support rep responded *twice* with a form email that was clearly designed for use by end-users having trouble with the LinkedIn website.  On the third try, he said he "sent [my] suggestion to [the] product team".  I don't have high hopes that it will end up being seen by the API team.  He also referred me to a [feedback page](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1376) which doesn't seem super helpful.  Meh.

Comment: FWIW, on a recent bug that I encountered, I managed to at least make SOME progress by just hitting up a LinkedIn developer on, well, LinkedIn. It might be worth a shot. You might have better luck if you can find a developer on the team responsible for the potentially buggy code.

Comment: Here I am again. Found another bug. This time in the pagination code... LinkedIn, what am I supposed to do? Gah!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not customer support for LinkedIn and this is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hidden away in the [Marketing Permissions Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/migrations/marketing-permissions-guide), I found a reference to LinkedIn's Zendesk help desk! ("LinkedIn Developer Support Portal")

I haven't tried submitting a ticket yet; please give it a shot and report back on if it worked for you!

https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

## Update

I submitted a bug report via the portal, and although it did take some time, I received a response directly from a competent engineer.

Thank you, LinkedIn, for the steps you're taking to improve your developer relations!

Comment: Well, just a few days later, I found another bug (ha) and submitted a request. Fingers crossed that this new support mechanism works!

Comment: See "Update" in answer!

Comment: But, how can I get an API Key, I see that you need to create an App for a business to have the api key.

Comment: @madhukarbs API keys are app-specific. Create an app at https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Answer (score 10):

The bug raising is a bit hidden on Linkedin.

Go to: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve

1. search for existing issues, others may have the same, maybe a workaround exists
2. or, click on `Get help from us`, and do the below:

An example is below:

- `Issue Type`: Jobs
- `In Which App or Site?`: LinkedIn (Website)
- `On What Device?`: Windows Laptop/Desktop
- `Your Question`: incorrect icon, should be a save icon, not bookmark icon, its confusing, see attachment
- `Attachment`:

If its API, try using below, whichever best suits you:

- `Issue Type`:                 Applications/Non-Mobile/Technical Support/Other
- `In Which App or Site?`:      Not App/Site Specific

And submit. That's all.

--

Additionally, you have a suggestion (not bug), you can use the below link:

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/feedback

Comment: Website bugs != API bugs

Comment: It need not be app/website issue. Use one of these settings --
Issue Type:  Applications/Non-Mobile/Technical Support/Other --
In Which App or Site?: Not App/Site Specific

Comment: The biggest challenge is that these generic feedback mechanisms seem to go to the wrong people - they go to customer support team instead of directly to the technical teams responsible for the features. My experience is poor with actually having action taken on a bug reported to the customer support folks. Maybe something has changed, though. Fingers crossed! I'll give this a shot next time I find an API bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While they make it absurdly difficult, it seems as though they have a few options available. It appears you can join their Private Bug Bounty Program. This should enable you to actively be rewarded for finding and posting bugs to them.

[Post announcing the program](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2015/06/private-bug-bounty-program)

[Bug Bounty Program Link on Hackerone (security site powered by hackers)](https://hackerone.com/linkedin)

If you would prefer to send them a one off email, it appears as though their mailing structure may give you some insight. Simply posting your bug or query to the correct email address may grab their attention. Chances are if you find a bug, it could lead to a security leak - so you could start with that.

[Link to their security policy with some mailing example options.](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/62924)

Additionally, if you simply mean you wish to send feedback to the team, then that can also be found, here:

[Send Feedback](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1376/sending-feedback-to-linkedin?lang=en)

On top of this, apparently officially joining their developer program should unlock additional support, by which I'm assuming you can report a bug.

[LinkedIn Developer Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs)

Comment: Yes, LinkedIn has somewhat clear paths for reporting *security* bugs. However, for several years now, they have not had a reliable mechanism for reporting non-security-related bugs. If you can find one, I'd love to upvote your answer. :)