# Why is LinkedIn removing URLs at the end of the status update `comment` field?

Tags: linkedin-api

The documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) contains this example:

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
    "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

This works so-so - In the resulting status update, "linkedin.com" is hyperlinked, the "developer." portion of the domain is not hyperlinked.  However, that's not the issue I'm concerned with.

Put simply, if `comment` ends in a URL, then the URL is entirely removed from the status update.  To demonstrate this, let's add the scheme in the original example so it is more easily parseable by LinkedIn (note the addition of `http://` before the domain):

```
{
  "comment": "Check out http://developer.linkedin.com!",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
    "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

This publishes as expected.  However, now we try removing the trailing exclamation mark as follows:

```
{
  "comment": "Check out http://developer.linkedin.com",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
    "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

When this status update is published, the resulting comment will read simply: "Check out ".  Example:

[image]

It seems to me that this is a bug.  Or, am I mistaken?  I'd normally submit this directly to the API provider, but [there's no clear mechanism for reporting LinkedIn API bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41860904/114558) and [LinkedIn itself has recommended posting here](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/stackoverflow).  So... yeah.

---

Update 1/9/18: I have received a report that this bug also manifests itself in Linkedin.com, not just via the LinkedIn API.

Update 1/12/18: Since it was discovered that this bug manifests itself on LinkedIn.com, I was able to help the LinkedIn rep reproduce the issue. After some back and forth, the rep responded by saying:

> The behavior is expected functionality by our Product Team. I am not able to go into why that is, but it is not a technical problem.

How, exactly, this is the desired behavior is beyond me. To me, it sounds like LinkedIn is saying this would be classified as "WONTFIX". Bummer - not just for us, but for all LinkedIn users.

Comment: (Sound of crickets and a door swinging on rusty hinges...)

Comment: (Winter sets in... everything is still.)