# LinkedIn Marketing Developer Platform "Review in Progress" for over 2 months

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been trying to get Marketing Developer Platform approved for multiple apps now and it has been stuck at "Review in Progress" for over 2 months. Contacting the direct support line was exactly zero help, and pushed me here. I've tagged this post according to instructions provided so hopefully someone from LinkedIn actually sees this and can give me some guidance.

There is no guidance on what is needed for successful approval and support avenues for LinkedIn are basically worthless, so here I am.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an appropriate place for customer support for LinkedIn, no matter what they claim.

Comment: Ok, well, this is where they have told me to go and I've had no other avenues that get any sort of results. I've been bounced around by their "support" team to about 4 different places at this point and have gotten literally nowhere.

LinkedIn, if you're reading this:
Your platform and your support is worse than awful.

Comment: @KClark_STF Hi, any update on the review status?

Comment: LinkedIn *does* finally have a proper developer help desk! https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745849/114558

Comment: P.S. I'm in the *exact* same situation, by the way. We submitted on June 24 and haven't heard back...

Comment: Any update on this for those who have been waiting for so long? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we finally got approval about a week and a half ago, after almost 4 months @raRaRa

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's still not a software development question

Answer (score 1):

your situation is complitly normal. Have patience and wait a little longer.